# MainScope vs GlobalScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the difference between GlobalScope and MainScope?

```
//Accessing data from Room
GlobalScope.launch {
            v.tvStoreName.text = pfViewModel.getStoreName()
            pageDetails.pageNumber = currentPage
            pageDetails.pageSize = pageSize
            pfViewModel.getTransactions(pageDetails, toolbarBuilder?.getDate()!!)
        }
```

The GlobalScope sometimes makes an error which is very hard to reproduce.

> Fatal Exception:
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
> original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

```
MainScope().launch {
            var storeName = ""
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                storeName = pfViewModel.getStoreName()
            }
            v.tvStoreName.text = storeName
        }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> What is the difference between GlobalScope and MainScope?

`MainScope` is a `CoroutineScope` that uses the `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher by default, which is bound to the main UI thread.

The `GlobalScope` is a `CoroutineScope` that has no dispatcher in its coroutine context. This means that the coroutines launched in this scope will use the `Dispatchers.Default` dispatcher, which is backed by a thread pool (sized based on the number of CPU cores you have).

The `GlobalScope` also has no `Job` in its context, which means structured concurrency doesn't apply. Coroutines launched in it are never cancelled automatically, so they need to be manually controlled. This is why it is usually discouraged to use it unless you have very specific needs.

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

This error occurs when you're trying to modify views from outside the main thread, which is what happens if you do this from coroutines launched in the `GlobalScope` (because it's backed by a separate thread pool).

In your second snippet, you are using `withContext(Dispatchers.Default)`, which only makes this part of the code run on that thread pool, but the rest runs on UI thread. This is why the update of the UI is ok there.

Note that Room already uses a dispatcher with a background thread pool for its queries, so you don't need to switch context manually like this, you can just call it from the UI thread.

Side note: using `MainScope().launch { .. }` like this is a bad idea, because it suffers from the same cancellation issue as `GlobalScope`. To use it properly, you would need to extract this scope into a variable/property so you can cancel it when appropriate. That said, it's easier to use an existing scope. Android [already provides a ready-to-use coroutine scope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) in components such as Activities which have a lifecycle (see `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` library). It's called `lifecycleScope`. You should launch your coroutines in this scope so they automatically get cancelled when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: In other words, I better use lifecycleScope in this correct? For some reason the current implementation of Room in this project does not allow accessing data as it is in main thread.

Comment: Yes, you should prefer `lifecycleScope` (or `viewModelScope` depending on which component you're in)

Comment: Follow up question, what if I am not in any scope such as `viewModelScope` nor `lifecycleScope`? Like the Coroutine is being implemented on a custom view library?

Comment: In general it's better to use suspend functions or flows in this case. But if you really need to start long-lived coroutines, you could create a custom scope that you cancel appropriately using whatever lifecycle your custom class has.